# Launch a dataproc job with --files through the rest API

Tags: rest, google-cloud-dataproc

I am able to submit a job to dataproc via the command line

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark --cluster=my_cluster --region=myregion --py-files file1.py script.py
```

I would like to transform this command line to a POST request to the rest api, https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/submit-job

However I am not able to understand how to set the

```
--py-files file1.py
```

parameter in the request. Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found that this can be accomplished though

```
 "pythonFileUris": [
    "gs://file1.py"
```